# Please explain rowspan and colspan, col and colgroup

Tags: css, xhtml, semantic-markup

Can anyone explain `rowspan` and `colspan`, `col` and `colgroup`? And are these W3C valid and semantically correct? Under which circumstances are these useful?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### colspan

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">people are...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>monkeys</td>
    <td>donkeys</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### rowspan

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">monkeys are...</th>
    <td>... real monkeys</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>... 'unreal' monkeys (people...)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### w3c

as you see, this is for connecting table-cells - and because this is sometimes neccessary, it's valid (RegDwights links will give more information...).

### col/colgroup

`colgroup` and `col` are used to set attributes to every line in the table (so you don't have to write `width="80"` for the first `td` in every line(`tr`)):

```
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="80">
    <col width="100">
    <col width="320">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>first line, first column</td>
    <td>first line, second column</td>
    <td>first line, third column</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more table-lines... -->
</table>
```

you can also group the cols, lets say the first and second column should get a `with` of 80, the third should get 320:

```
<table border="1">
  <colgroup width="80" span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup width="320" span="1"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>first line, first column</td>
    <td>first line, second column</td>
    <td>first line, third column</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more table-lines... -->
</table>
```

Comment: added col/colgroup, hope this helps.

Comment: can we use width="80" ? isn't it deprecated

Comment: if i remember right, width is only deprecated for td, th, pre and... something else - but if you don't wand to use it, you can have the same effect by using stylesheets.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are all recommended by W3C. Here are direct links to the documentation:

- [`col`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element)
- [`colgroup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element)
- [`colspan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-colspan)
- [`rowspan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-rowspan)

Answer (score 2):

`rowspan` and `colspan` are attributes that allow the designer to 'merge' cells - much like the same command in Excel (for example).

`col` and `colgroup` allow the designer to apply css to a vertical column, rather than having to apply css to individual cells in a column. Without these, this task would be much more difficult as html tables are row-based.

All four of these are valid.

For future reference, try http://reference.sitepoint.com/html