# Using CSS Reset in Firefox creates black lines between table td's

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

I am using Eric Meyer's CSS reset which works well but the problem I am having in Firefox is that the `table {border: collapse;}` is creating black lines between the td's in Firefox.

If I set the `table {border: seperate;}` the problem is solved but then IE7 creates these white gaps between the td's.

Has anyone else come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-spacing: 0;` or `border-color: transparent` to remove the black gaps between table columns. Use related questions to workaround the lack of `border-collapse`:

- [Please explain rowspan and colspan, col and colgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416453/please-explain-rowspan-and-colspan-col-and-colgroup)
- [HTML Table Colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961872/html-table-colspan)
- [rowspans and colspans in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614022/rowspans-and-colspans-in-html-email)
- [Colspan all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns)